# select tag option foreach one to many relationship returns supplier_id equal to NULL

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

I have a One to Many relationship between Supplier and Product.

**Model Product**

```
class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'description',
        'barcode',
        'quantity',
        'price',
        'supplier_id'
    ];

    public function supplier()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Supplier::class);
    }
}
```

**Model Supplier**

```
class Supplier extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

In the creation of the product I print a select which brings me back all the available suppliers and therefore I select the supplier of interest.

When I create the product I get the following problem: The product is created successfully but in the **supplier_id** column (integrity constraint) of the created product I get NULL.

This is my first time using select this way.

Is there a setting problem in the select?

**View create**

```
<x-layout>
    <div class="container mt-5 mb-5">

        <form action="{{route('product.store')}}" method="post">
            @csrf
            <div class="row mt-3">
                <div class="mb-3 col-12 col-md-5">

                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="supplier_id" value="{{$supplier->id}}">
                    
                    <div>
                        <label for="suppliers" class="form-label">Supplier</label>
                        <select name="supplier" id="suppliers" value="{{ $product->supplier_id }}">
                            @foreach($suppliers as $supplier)
                            <option value="{{$supplier->id}}">{{$supplier->name}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <label for="description" class="form-label">Description</label>
                    <textarea name="description" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control p-3" required>{{ old('description') }}</textarea>

                    <label for="barcode" class="form-label">BarCode</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control p-3" name="barcode" value="{{ old('barcode') }}" required>


                    <label for="quantity" class="form-label">Quantity</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control p-3" name="quantity" value="{{ old('quantity') }}" required>

            
                    <label for="price" class="form-label">Price</label>
                    <input type="number" step="any" class="form-control p-3" name="price" value="{{ old('price') }}">

                </div>
            </div>


            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-5 py-3 px-4 mt-3 ms-3 fs-5">ADD</button>


        </form>
    </div>

</x-layout>
```

Can anyone kindly help me?

Comment: Your `<select>` has a `name="suppliers"` attribute, not `supplier_id`

Comment: "_When I create the product_" How do you create the product, can you post the code (in your question)?

Comment: fyi, a `<select>` element doesn't use the `value="{{ $product->supplier_id }}"` attribute

Comment: @brombeer Can you kindly put the well-written select as the answer?